# In data flow coverage, does returning a variable use it?

Tags: testing, code-coverage, dataflow, test-coverage

I have a small question in my mind. I researched it on the Internet but no-one is providing the exact answer. My question is:

In data flow coverage criteria, say there is a method which finally returns variable `x`. When drawing the graph for that method, is that return statement considered to be a use of `x`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a `return` statement uses the value that it returns. I couldn't find an authoritative reference that says so in plain English either, but here are two arguments:

- A `return` statement passes control from one part of a program to another, just like a method call does. The value being returned is analogous to a function parameter. `return` therefore is a use just like being a function parameter is a use.
- The other kind of use in data flow analysis is when a value leaves the program and has some effect on the outside world, for example by being printed. If we're analyzing a method, rather than an entire program, `return` causes the value to leave the scope which we're analyzing. So it's a use for the same reason that printing is a use.

Comment: I buy the argument about a value leaving the program under the assumption the outside world is going to be affected by it.  I'm not so sure I buy the argument about the returned value.    Imagine I want to know if Y is "data flow covered, and I have an statement "X:=Y" but there in no use of X anywhere.  I think you'll agree that Y isn't really covered.  But how is this different than "return Y"?  The real difference is that it is not so obvious that the returned value is used.  You'd have to do a global data flow analysis to determine that (and I think you should).  ...

Comment: So for me a "return Y" statement by itself shouldn't be evidence that Y got used.   I think you should see a (nontrivial) use of the returned value.

Comment: Overall that's true, but it's the game you play when analyzing a method in isolation.

Comment: If you insist on testing the function in isolation, you can make this argument; also if you test a block of code in isolation, and it assigns a value to a variable X not used inside the block.   Testing with isolation is certainly better than not testing, or testing using weaker criteria, but normally we are testing code embedded in a larger application.   At some point you should test the code not-in-isolation; if you want to use data flow coverage for the not-in-isolation tests then I think you have validate that dataflows leaving isolated chunks indeed get used outside that chunk.

Comment: Yes, if function A did not use but only returned a value you'd need to look at the data flow in all of A's callers (and their callers, etc.) to know whether the value was used in the program.